# Magento 2 sales_order_save_after doesn´t trigger when edit order in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, event-observer, adminhtml

I had configure a observer to listen the event **`sales_order_save_after`** when the order changes its status.

In **`Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="<observer_name>" instance="<Vendor>\<Module>\Observer\OrderPlace" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

When the user create the order in checkout the observer workds fine. But when the administrator change the order in admin, the observer is ignored. I tried copy the file **`Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`** to **`Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`** but nothing change.

What could it be?